# Setting width & padding: ensure that the width includes/compensates for padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

In CSS, when I set an elements width to 100px then I set its padding to 10px, **it's actual width is 120px.**

*Note: I am unsure if this occurs all the time or only when the position = absolute like all my elements have.*

Is there a setting where if I tell an element to be 100px in width(& have a padding of 10px) that its width will always be 100px? Is there a way to ensure that the width compensates for the padding?

```
myClass { width: 100px; padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing support Firefox, Safari/WebKit, Opera and IE8